# using VS2013 but still get "The builds tools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found." error

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio **2013** on a Windows 7-64 machine and still got the below error.
I have exactly the same reg key setting under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild** to my coworker who can compile the solution fine. we are using the same VS2013.

it's weird that my log shows "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\ **V110** \Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(44,5)", but not **V120**.  anyone knows why?

appreciate any clue and help, been stuck for a few days.

> 1>------ Build started: Project: MyProject01, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   2>------ Build started: Project: MyProject02, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   1>**C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(44,5): error MSB8020: The builds tools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found.** To build using the v120 build tools, either click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC++ Projects...". Install v120 to build using the v120 build tools.
>   2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(44,5): error MSB8020: The builds tools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found. To build using the v120 build tools, either click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC++ Projects...". Install v120 to build using the v120 build tools.
>   3>------ Build started: Project: MyProject03, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   3>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(44,5): error MSB8020: The builds tools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found. To build using the v120 build tools, either click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC++ Projects...". Install v120 to build using the v120 build tools.
>   4>------ Build started: Project: MyProject04, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(44,5): error MSB8020: The builds tools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found. To build using the v120 build tools, either click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC++ Projects...". Install v120 to build using the v120 build tools.
>   5>------ Build started: Project: MyProject05, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
>   5>CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'D:_Vault\Workspaces\MyProject05_Parser\Debug\MyProject05Parser.dll' could not be found
>   6>------ Build started: Project: MyProject06, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   6>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(44,5): error MSB8020: The builds tools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found. To build using the v120 build tools, either click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC++ Projects...". Install v120 to build using the v120 build tools.
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 6 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: are you sure the selected platform toolset in your project properties is set to `Visual Studio 2013 (v120)` and not `Visual Studio 2012 (v110)`, which could be the case after an upgrade (and would mean your coworker has VS2012 installed and is using that toolset instead of the new one)

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I root caused the issue, it's because some other project on the development machine has a system environment variable "VCTargetsPath" which is pointing to v110.

Comment: Either post this as an answer yourself then, or delete your question: else it just reains one of the many, many unanswered ones even though you actually got an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I root caused the issue, it's because some other project on the development machine has a system environment variable "***VCTargetsPath***" which is pointing to v110.   after removing this environment variable the compilation starts working.  It seems the the environment variable can overwrite the effect of ***HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild***, where there is one ***VCTargetsPath*** subkey and pointing to v120 already.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue because the VisualStudioVersion environment variable was set to "11.0" [rather than "12.0" (2013) or "14.0" (2015) or not set at all].

Comment: This really helped